# Ajax UpdatePanel not working in IE9

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am using updatepanel to avoid the postback and the code is working fine in IE8 and firefox but not in IE9. I also tried installing latest ajax toolkit from codeplex but it did not help me either.Please help me with this. My code is something like below/....

```
<table width="800px">
                                <tr>
                                <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upCountry">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <td class="TextLabelForHeader" width="300px">
                                        Country:
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlCountry"
                                            ErrorMessage="*" InitialValue="Select.." ValidationGroup="VGHeader"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left">
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                            AutoPostBack="true" OnDataBound="ddlCountry_DataBound" onchange="SelectCurrency(this);"
                                            ValidationGroup="VGHeader">
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left">
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upCurrency">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <td class="TextLabelForHeader" width="300px">
                                        Currency:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left">
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCurrency" runat="server" ValidationGroup="VGHeader">
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left">
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="TextLabelForHeader" width="300px">
                                        Client:
                                        <%--<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" 
                                                        ControlToValidate="ddlClient" ErrorMessage="*" InitialValue="Select.." 
                                                        ValidationGroup="VGHeader"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>--%>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtClient"
                                            ErrorMessage="*" ValidationGroup="VGHeader"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left">
                                        <%--    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlClient" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="143px" Enabled="false"
                                                        OnDataBound="ddlClient_DataBound" onchange="DisplayTextbox(this);" ValidationGroup="VGHeader">
                                                    </asp:DropDownList>--%>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtClient" runat="server" Width="143px" ReadOnly="true" ValidationGroup="VGHeader"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <%--<div id="form_ProductContainer" style="display: none;">
                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewClientName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    </div>--%>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="TextLabelForHeader" style="text-align: left;">
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnContinue" runat="server" OnClick="btnContinue_Click" Text="Continue"
                                            ValidationGroup="VGHeader" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
```

Comment: This is actually a visual webpart usercontrol code in sharepoint 2010, and i have not specifically used anything thinking sharepoint supports ajax by default. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Discussion:** Is it vital that it uses IE9 as is? If it isn't then you could just force it to render as IE8 with the following code inserted in the head section of the page or master page.

**Possible Solution:**

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=IE8" />
```

**Updated Response**

**Identified Issue:** I had a look at your code and you have no update Panel inside the last TR element. I imagine now that the code originally worked in IE8 because you probably had another update panel that covered the entire table.

Comment: I looked through your code, identified the issue and updated my response. Cheers